# How to add my own plugin to Cooja

Tags: java, contiki

I would like to add my own plugin to Cooja. I would like to extend the Visualizer.class in order to have two of them in Cooja.

Answer (score 1):

This video shows you how to add your own plugin to Cooja extending the Visualizer.java

https://youtu.be/qA0ZB7xVFW0

I explain the video. You need to modify the file Gui.java

```
/home/user/contiki-2.x/tools/cooja/java/se/sics/cooja/Gui.java
```

adding the following code:

```
// Register My Own plugins
Class<? extends Plugin> pluginClass1 = tryLoadClass(this, Plugin.class,
"se.sics.cooja.plugins.Tree");
if (pluginClass1 != null) {
    registerPlugin(pluginClass1);
    logger.info("Loaded plugin class: " + pluginClass1);
} else {
    logger.warn("Could not load plugin class: se.sics.cooja.plugins.Tree" );
}
```

Additionally, you must create your own plugin named Tree.java extending Visualizer.java. The following is the code for creating the plugin Tree.java

```
package se.sics.cooja.plugins;

import se.sics.cooja.GUI;
import se.sics.cooja.Simulation;
import se.sics.cooja.plugins.Visualizer;
import se.sics.cooja.PluginType;
import se.sics.cooja.ClassDescription;

@ClassDescription("NetworkTree")
@PluginType(PluginType.SIM_STANDARD_PLUGIN)

public class Tree extends Visualizer{
    public Tree(Simulation simulation, GUI gui) {
        super(simulation, gui);
        this.setLocation(1, 401);
        this.setSize(400, 400);
    }
}
```

Tree.java is located in

```
/home/user/contiki-2.x/tools/cooja/java/se/sics/cooja/plugins/Tree.java
```

Then, you compile Cooja

```
ant clean 
ant run
```

and now you have in Cooja your own plugin which extends Visualizer.java

:)